# Typescript definition for values function which always return array of argument

Tags: typescript

```
export type Primitive =
  | null
  | undefined
  | string
  | number
  | boolean
  | symbol
  | bigint;

function values<T extends any[]>(value: T): T;
function values<T extends Primitive>(value: T): [T] {
  return Array.isArray(value) ? value : [value];
}
```

I want to build a function to always return `array`.

my attempt so far for the values function, but it's not working. Does anyone have a better idea or suggestion? thanks in advance.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=15&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcAKUCWBbTNMBuqAvAFBxwA%20cAdgK4A2D5VcdNAJsAGaY3AcW1AM4wsNAOZDadbACNgUaXIgQGwAIY1pwxPLXLMEvjADcpUt3YBjfBBpwCGhnWDCAPABU4oGME7CcFqIANoAugB8ABROLsAAXHCeAJSJnuZWNLaY9o7Orh7evv4cgRg4eITA0bGuaalwIZ5hcADeLFDAMHRQDgCCUFAaiAB0mMIDQ4gx%20cDJcAD8eXFwiSG1wGHmAL4WQA)

Comment: What does this have to do with lodash? If you're really trying to type the [`_.values()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#values) function, it would look very different from what you currently have.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I have removed the lodash reference, just need a function to always return the array of argument.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen bascially this logic: Array.isArray(value) ? value : [value] by type safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have to add more overloadings:

```js
export type Primitive =
  | null
  | undefined
  | string
  | number
  | boolean
  | symbol
  | bigint;

function values<T extends Primitive>(value: T): [T];
function values<T>(value: Array<T>): Array<T>;
function values<T extends Primitive>(value: T): [T] | Array<T> {
  if (Array.isArray(value)) {
    const x = value
    return value
  } else {
    return [value]
  }
}


const x = values(1) // [1]
const y = values('hello') // ['hello']
const z = values([1,2,3]) // number[]
```

Comment: Thank you captain-yossarian.